# Using wallet methods throughout the program in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, service, helper, wallet

I created a wallet in Laravel that I want the operations of this wallet to be stored in one place and can be used in the whole program, for example:

```
WalletClass::deposit(25000,auht()->id());
```

Which method should I use? Is it better to write a service provider or fecads and... or do we have a better method?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one instance of the Wallet shared across the entire application you can [register a singleton](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#binding-a-singleton).

This allows you to use `App::make(WalletClass)` anywhere and get the same instance.

> The singleton method binds a class or interface into the container that should only be resolved one time.

Be careful though, do you really want every request sharing the same object? For something like a wallet it would like you would need an instance per connection. If that's the case you can use a [scoped singleton](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#binding-scoped).

> The scoped method binds a class or interface into the container that should only be resolved one time within a given Laravel request / job lifecycle

Regarding the naming of your class, it's generally not a good idea to suffix everything with what it is, such as `WalletClass` or `WalletInterface`. What's wrong with just calling it a `Wallet`?

Comment: There is no problem, just because I had a model named `Wallet`, I named it `WalletClass`
You know, I want a method that can be used simply like models

Comment: I see what you mean now, it's not the instance of a class you need to use it is the _actions_ performed on the Wallet. In these cases I find it useful to extract the functionality in to  classes derived from a base `Action` class. Each action has an `execute` function to perform the action, with data needed by the action passed in when it is constructed.

Comment: Once you get a number of actions it can be useful to have an `ActionFactory` with static functions which construct the actions. The factory also decouples the caller of the action from the implementation they get back. In Laravel you can use the ServiceContainer to perform a similar service.